# Modify text in Content Control where there is placeholder text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a rich text Content Control called `TestContent`.

Example:
[image]

In my code, the sub `RunExample` initializes the range of said Content Control and writes the example text into the end of the range using `AddText` sub:

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim TestContentRange As Word.Range

Sub RunExample()

    'Initialize the range as the range of Content Control
    Set TestContentRange = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("TestContent")(1).Range
    'Write the "Hello World" to the content Control
    AddText "Hello World"
End Sub


Sub AddText(TextBit As String)
    Dim SlaveRange As Word.Range
    Set SlaveRange = TestContentRange
    SlaveRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    SlaveRange.Text = TextBit
End Sub
```

I get

> Runtime error 6124 : You are not allowed to edit this selection because it is protected.

As I understand it, this is because when the Content Control is empty the placeholder text gets in the way and the placeholder is prohibited from direct editing hence the error. For example if I put some text into the Content Control like `TestContentRange.Text = "!"` the code runs.

Example:

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim TestContentRange As Word.Range

Sub RunExample()
    Set TestContentRange = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("TestContent")(1).Range
    TestContentRange.Text = "!"
    AddText "Hello World"
End Sub


Sub AddText(TextBit As String)
    Dim SlaveRange As Word.Range
    Set SlaveRange = TestContentRange
    SlaveRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    SlaveRange.Text = TextBit
End Sub
```

How do I avoid that placeholder text? Should I make a check of the range being empty in the `AddText` sub or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is that you want to either replace or add to the text of a content control, depending on the existing text in the control.

To check if a content control still contains its placeholder text simply compare the controls Range.Text to its PlaceholderText property. To do that your AddText routine needs to work with the actual content control not just its range.

```
Sub RunExample()
  AddTextToContentControl ActiveDocument, "Test Content", "Hello World"
End Sub

Sub AddTextToContentControl(WorkDoc As Document, CCTitle As String, TextToAdd As String)
  Dim ctrl As ContentControl
  Set ctrl = GetContentControlByTitle(WorkDoc, CCTitle)
  If Not ctrl Is Nothing Then
    If ctrl.Range.Text = ctrl.PlaceholderText Then
      'replace the placeholder text
      ctrl.Range.Text = TextToAdd
    Else
      'add to the existing text
      ctrl.Range.Text = ctrl.Range.Text & " " & TextToAdd
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Function GetContentControlByTitle(SearchDoc As Document, CCTitle As String) As ContentControl
  Dim ctrl As ContentControl
  For Each ctrl In SearchDoc.ContentControls
    If ctrl.Title = CCTitle Then
      Set GetContentControlByTitle = ctrl
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're collapsing the range, the macro tries to append your text to the default text in the CC, which is not possible. Just take out this line:

```
SlaveRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
```

Then it runs as expected and replaces the default.

Comment: I wanted my `addText` subroutine to add data to the end of the range of the content control, not replace it.

Comment: But in your question, you proposed checking to see if the CC was empty first before adding text. Why would you want to append text to the default placeholder text?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something that makes use of .ShowingPlaceholderText, e.g. :

```
' This assumes there is at least one CC titled "TestContent"
With ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("TestContent")(1)
  If .ShowingPlaceholderText Then
    .Range.Text = "Hello World"
  Else
    .Range.InsertAfter "Hello World"
  End If
End With
```

Otherwise, a design problem occurs if the CC currently contains text that is identical to the placeholder text. Do you want text that is identical to the placeholder text, but is real text, to be replaced as if it was actually placeholder text, or do you want to append "Hello World" ?